# Выбрать не повторяющиеся строки из таблицы mysql по параметру

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Вопрос вроде бы простенький, но иногда и такое ставит в тупик.

Есть mysql таблица сообщений вида:

```
From  |  TO   | TEXT  | Data |
------------------------------
name1 | name3 | text1 | Data1
name1 | name3 | text2 | Data2
name2 | name3 | text3 | Data3
name3 | name1 | text4 | Data4
```

...

Необходимо выбрать строки так чтобы получилось следующее:

```
From  |  TO   | TEXT  | Data |
------------------------------
name1 | name3 | text1 | Data1
name2 | name3 | text3 | Data3
```

...

Простые запросы с добавлением: DISTINCT или GROUP BY не помогают, присутствует параметр:

```
WHERE to='name3'
```

Если предложите решение на (php+ PDO) будет вообще замечательно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аааа. черт. сам решил спустя пару минут :)
Досточен запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `to`='name3' GROUP BY `from`;
```